# Eclipse problem. Error validating C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\devices.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, validation

Recently Eclipse started showing this error in its Error Log:

> Error validating C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\devices.xml

I also noticed, when editing XML layout files (layout mode) all the dropdowns for Devices, Config and Locale 
are empty. I remember befere I used to be able to select various devices sizez, orientations, etc. here.

Any idea how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed by reinstalling everything. JDK, eclipse, android sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old but for anyone in the future that sees this try this.  Unplug all android phones from computer.  Delete the devices.xml. Restart Eclipse.  That worked for me.